# $C^\omega(\Omega)\cap C^\infty_0(\Omega)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ denote an open connected set in $\mathbf{R}$ (AKA open interval). Is it true and how can we prove it that $C^\omega(\Omega)\cap C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ consists of the zero function alone, i.e. that an analytic function having compact support vanishes identically?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Let $$Z(f) = \{ x\in \Omega : f \equiv 0 \text{ in a neighbourhood of } x\}.$$

Evidently, $Z(f)$ is open, and if $x_0 \in \overline{Z(f)}$, consider the Taylor expansion of $f$ about $x_0$. Since $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $Z(f)$, all coefficients must vanish, and since $f$ is analytic, it follows that $f$ vanishes in a neighbourhood of $x_0$, i.e. $x_0 \in Z(f)$. Thus $Z(f)$ is open and closed, and since it is not empty ($f \in C_c(\Omega)$), and $\Omega$ connected, $Z(f) = \Omega$, i.e. $f\equiv 0$.